# C++//How to store values from user input?

Tags: c++

I am writing a mastermind game code and I want to display userGuess. But not only displaying the current guess, but also displaying all the userGuess that user made.
For example... If userGuess was 0 0 1 1, then
the board should display
[0 0 1 1]
and if the user made another guess like 2 2 3 3, then I want to display

[0 0 1 1]

[2 2 3 3]

and so forth up to 4x10 matrix..
I am working inside the class so I have no idea how should I approach this method!

---

Here's my code!

I use this function to get user input.

```
    void Game::getUserGuess()
{
    int guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4;
    std::cout << "Type 4 colors that you want to check: ";
    std::cin >> guess_1 >> guess_2 >> guess_3 >> guess_4;
    currGuess.setGuess(guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4);
}

void Game::displayUserGuess() 
{

    // displaying user guess code
    std::cout << "Your Guess: " << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[0] << "|" << gameboard[1] << "|" << gameboard[2] << "|" << gameboard[3] << "|    White Pegs: " << whitePegs <<  std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[4] << "|" << gameboard[5] << "|" << gameboard[6] << "|" << gameboard[7] << "|    Black Pegs: " << blackPegs << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[8] << "|" << gameboard[9] << "|" << gameboard[10] << "|" << gameboard[11] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[12] << "|" << gameboard[13] << "|" << gameboard[14] << "|" << gameboard[15] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[16] << "|" << gameboard[17] << "|" << gameboard[18] << "|" << gameboard[19] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[20] << "|" << gameboard[21] << "|" << gameboard[22] << "|" << gameboard[23] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[24] << "|" << gameboard[25] << "|" << gameboard[26] << "|" << gameboard[27] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[28] << "|" << gameboard[29] << "|" << gameboard[30] << "|" << gameboard[31] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[32] << "|" << gameboard[33] << "|" << gameboard[34] << "|" << gameboard[35] << "|" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "|" << gameboard[36] << "|" << gameboard[37] << "|" << gameboard[38] << "|" << gameboard[39] << "|" << std::endl;

    
}


void Game::playGame()
{   

    colorTable();
    do {
        
        secretCode;
        getUserGuess();
        generateFeedback();
        if (isWinner()) {
            std::cout << "You won!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "[[ Wrong ]]" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            numGuesses++;
        }
        blackPegs = 0;
        whitePegs = 0;
    } while (!outOfGuesses());

}
```

Basically, I want to store user_input to my gameboard but I do not know how to use vector or array well.. It keeps giving me an error once I use vector..

I want user to see their results after feedback. So if the user made one move and check their result, then they could see the previous result!

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::cin` and the `>>` operator to read into variables? Then do that four times using four different variables, and print the variables in the way you want them.

Comment: Or maybe a vector or array rather than separate variables?

Comment: Yeah..! I do know that part but I want to store the value to the outside of scope. I am using a class member function to getting a user input but every time I loop for asking user input, i want to store their values into my storage...

Comment: can you show some of codes for clarification or explain clearly what you exactly want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store your guesses directly into the game board:

```
void Game::getUserGuess()
{
    int guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4;
    std::cout << "Type 4 colors that you want to check: ";
    std::cin >> guess_1 >> guess_2 >> guess_3 >> guess_4;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4] = guess_1;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 1] = guess_2;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 2] = guess_3;
    gameboard[numGuesses*4 + 3] = guess_4;
    currGuess.setGuess(guess_1, guess_2, guess_3, guess_4);
}
```

Comment: I have a 4x10 board. Does this method will continuously append the values into the board?

Comment: It should do, difficult to tell without a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a some tips to help how to approach the problem. With these tips I'm sure you can write this and other codes.

First you need to divide you problem in part to get your answer. Try to see the big picture and after that go deep.

As you said, you need to store a several data and the question already gave the size of this storage. It is a maximum of 4x10 matrix, or a matrix that store another matrix of (4 elements).

You can use the std::array or std::vector to do that. To decide with one use, important to note you have 'if the user made another guess'. That means you aren't sure how many times the userGuess will guess, but you know every guess has 4. To represent it in code it will be:

```
std::vector<std::array<int,4>> gameboard;
```

Next step you want to ask the maximum of 10x to user his userGuess his guesses. (Let put aside for a while how to ask). Also you say you are working in a class then you will have a function member to add new guess. It could be something like that:

```
void YourClass::Add() {
     if (gameboard.size() < 10) {        //Here you won't let more than 10 guesses
        gameboard.emplace_back();          //New guess added
        //will ask the 4 guesses
     }
}
```

The next step is ask the 4 guesses. That require a loop like this:

```
for (int g = 0; g < 4; ++g) {
    //fulfill the matrix here
}
```

Now, you just need to fulfill the elements

```
cin >> gameboard.back()[g];
```

Comment: I feel like I am getting it there..! I am trying to create vector, but my IDE said array is not a template for the part std::vector<array<int, 4>> gameboard;  I am trying to create vector inside my class, but it is keep giving me error how should I fix this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: Didi you declare it with #include <array>?

Comment: Nvm! It worked again! I had to put std::// std::vector<std::array<int, 4>> gameboard; is this form okay?

Comment: It the code, Guesses.emplace_back(); what does Guesses is referring to?